# Why is reflexive "se" not used in the sentence "Las clases empiezan"?

Tags: reflexivos

In Russian language *"Las clases empiezan"* is said *"Классы начинаются"*, where the ending *"тся"* shows reflexiveness. This is because we consider that classes (*"las clases"*) start themselves.
I see that in Spanish it is not like that. Why is it so? Why is it not said *"Las clases se empiezan"*?

Comment: Not all phrases in all languages are 1-1 analogues. Would it help to think of empezar as *'to begin'*, rather than *'to start'*?

Answer (score 1):

The only answer I can think of for your question is that

> Languages have many differences.  If all verbs matched up perfectly, in meaning and usage, such as transitive/intransitive, reflexive/not reflexive, then we would lose the beautiful variability and richness of the world's languages.  How boring that would be!

However, I thought you might like to know that there's another way of expressing the same concept, that *is* reflexive (pronominal):

**iniciarse**

> Las clases se inician el 27 de agosto.

Comment: _Las clases se dan inicio_ suena rarísimo en España. Me suena mucho mejor _las clases se inician_.

Comment: @fedorqui - I hope you don't mind, I'm going to change my answer and use your verb.  It sounds better to my ear too, and it fits the bill of being a reflexive verb that  can be used for the same purpose as *empezar* or *comenzar*.

Comment: Of course! _Dar inicio_ is normally used in a formal way and without reflexives: _Hoy dio inicio la legislatura en el Parlamento_.

Answer (score 0):

I traveled through South America for 9 months and I can say that some people use **se** for almost any verb. They are natives and they use incorrect grammar, but that does not mean they are speaking correctly.

Also every language is a reflection of a culture. There are rules that come to be through a long process and they do not depend on any opinion. So do not worry about the grammar so much.

Just try to communicate with people and you will learn why, either way.

Answer (score 0):

'*Las clases*' doesn't start themselves. A group of people begins them -students and teacher-, usually at a given schedule. Adding reflexive 'se' implies that they start wether someone is present or not.